# What is the ruling for someone who does other's assignment?

Tags: sheker-false

Assignments are meant to evaluate a students performance and a student is also graded based on the numbers that include numbers that he gets on those assignments. It is common in students that they do others assignments and vice versa. It is also common that students put their assignments as a task on online freelancing sites such as fiverr. I personally believe that both the person who does other's assignments and the one who gets those done by others are committing sin. However, I don't know if I can back my opinion with Tanakh and Talmud. Plz guide me in this regard with regards to both the individuals respectively. Shalom Aleichem.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/is-cheating-in-a-test-an-averah

Comment: @DonielF my question is different then the one you provided the link to. My question is can you pay for somebody to do your test for you.

Comment: @Counter-Missionary Why should payment make a difference?

Comment: @DonielF because I want it to.

Comment: I don't think that this is a clear-cut question to answer. I have helped my children do their assignments many times. It was almost to the point where I did everything. There's a fine but still halachically vague line, I think, between helping and doing the work for them.

Comment: @SünD I think it is.